# unable to install scikit-learn from git using jupyter notebook in my windows

Tags: python, windows, git, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

i'm trying to import sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix, but since it is not in the normal package what I'm trying to do is install it using `!pip install git+http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git` in my windows using jupyter notebook. I used command prompt as well but the same problem occurred. but when I'm doing this an error is popping up which is shown bellow

it's saying something related to "Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:"

have shown the complete dialogue below.
Please Help!!!

```
!pip install git+http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

```
Collecting git+http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
  Cloning http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git to c:\users\intel\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-bg_zxcrm
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.22.dev0) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.22.dev0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.22.dev0) (0.14.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-learn: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-learn: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\INTEL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-bg_zxcrm\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-vp_d4jnx --python-tag cp37:
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
      return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
  IndexError: list index out of range

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-bg_zxcrm\setup.py", line 290, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-bg_zxcrm\setup.py", line 286, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-bg_zxcrm\setup.py", line 174, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1037, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1006, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 943, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 81, in configuration
      maybe_cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-bg_zxcrm\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 43, in maybe_cythonize_extensions
      with_openmp = check_openmp_support()
    File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-bg_zxcrm\sklearn\_build_utils\openmp_helpers.py", line 84, in check_openmp_support
      extra_postargs=openmp_flags)
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
      self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
      self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
    File "C:\PROGRAMDATA\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
  distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.20.1
    Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.20.1:
  Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\scikit_learn-0.20.1-py3.7.egg-info\\dependency_links.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting a similar error I was able to install `scikit-learn` by following the instructions from the official site https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html.

#### Error caused by file path length limit on Windows

It can happen that pip fails to install packages when reaching the default path size limit of Windows if Python is installed in a nested location such as the AppData folder structure under the user home directory, for instance:

```
Collecting scikit-learn
...
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\sklearn\\datasets\\tests\\data\\openml\\292\\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz'
```

In this case it is possible to lift that limit in the Windows registry by using the regedit tool:

Type “regedit” in the Windows start menu to launch regedit.

Go to the `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` key.

Edit the value of the `LongPathsEnabled` property of that key and set it to 1.

Reinstall scikit-learn (ignoring the previous broken installation):

`pip install --exists-action=i scikit-learn`

Comment: Why would they *disable* long paths by default? Seems dumb